# How to use storybook with real data?

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon, nextjs-storybook

I am using storybook in a react project and I want to create an iframe that points out to one of my stories of a different project. In addition I want to add a query to the params in order to mock real data into my story and print it out. Lets assume that the story book of the other project is public and running on the web.

For example in my react project i am trying to add:

```
<iframe
        src=`http://localhost:6006/?path=/story/widgets-teaser-1big-small-grid--widget-teaser-1-big-small-grid-component&full=1&shortcuts=false&singleStory=true?dataurl=${exampleApi}`
        width="800"
        height="700"
      >
</iframe>
```

But when I do that I get an error :

Couldn't find story matching 'widgets-picture-widget-picture-full--widget-picture-full-component?dataurl=exampleApi'

My idea was to pass the ApiUrl from which I will get the data into storybook using the params. Then do an axios call inside the story and pass those data to the component instead of the dummydata that I have created.

Any tips, help ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<iframe
        src=`http://localhost:6006/?path=/story/widgets-teaser-1big-small-grid--widget-teaser-1-big-small-grid-component&full=1&shortcuts=false&singleStory=true&dataurl=${exampleApi}`
        width="800"
        height="700"
      >
</iframe>
```

Basically just replacing the ? with & solves the problem. And indeed now I can call my storybook from any project, and I can pass the api Url that will serve me the data I need to load any story with any data!